# %CD% to find current directory

Tags: windows, directory, environment-variables

When I write instructions to describe steps to be taken on a computer I make extensive use of both Windows `%CD%` representation of the current directory, and on Linux the `$PWD` equivalent.

I have been told by one user that `%CD%` is not set on their Windows machine.

When they issue

```
echo %CD%
```

nothing is shown. What can cause this? What can I get the user to do, so that I can rely on `%CD%` being available?

Comment: `%cd%` is an internal/implicit variable, so maybe they use an non standard command line processor, or something in their environment has called `set cd=something`. https://superuser.com/ may be best suited for that type of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things to bear in mind here, so I'll address your questions individually.

> 1. What can cause this?

If `Command Extensions` are disabled, then certain Shell Variables such as `%CD%` will be not accessible.

You can check if they are enabled by running

`reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"`

Which will give something like...

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
    CompletionChar    REG_DWORD    0x9
    DefaultColor    REG_DWORD    0x0
    EnableExtensions    REG_DWORD    0x1 <- check this is 0x1 not 0x0
    PathCompletionChar    REG_DWORD    0x9
```

Alternatively as Simon Mourier commented - they could have `SET` cd to something else, or nothing. e.g.

`SET cd=`

then

```
echo %CD%
```

gives nothing...

> 2. What can I get the user to do, so that I can rely on %CD% being
>    available?

Try getting them to launch CMD with the `/E:ON` flag to enable `Command Extensions` e.g.

```
cmd /E:ON
```

Then running checking...

```
C:\Program Files>echo %CD%
C:\Program Files
```

The `/E:ON` flag only alters the `Command Extensions` for that session - so to persist the change they would need to alter the registry on their machine, setting the `REG_DWORD`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\EnableExtensions` to `0x1`

Alternatively to all this, you can use the Dynamic Global variable `%__CD__%` instead of `%CD%`

`%__CD__%` is the same as `%CD%` except it has a trailing backslash.

e.g.

```
C:\Program Files>echo %__CD__%
C:\Program Files\
```

`%__CD__%` also has the benefit of being `readonly` - meaning it is impossible to use `SET`, etc, to define or alter it.